# .net moving file from windows to linux using winscp

Tags: c#, .net

Writing  code to move file from windows client to remote linux server.
The code executes fine by keeping static file name, but while passing filename dynamically, code doesnt works as expected.Below is the code, pls suggest.
Thanks,
Afzal.

```
  var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe")
                        {
                            Arguments = @"/command ""option batch on"" ""option confirm off"" ""open userx:pwdx@10.1.1.1"" ""put C:\Mobile\Attachments\20.jpeg /tmp/"" ""/log=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.log"" ""exit""",//working fine
                            //tried this but not working @"/command ""option batch on"" ""option confirm off"" ""open auserx:pwdx@10.1.1.1"" ""put C:\Mobile\Attachments\"+filename +" "+" /tmp/"+ @"/log=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.log"" ""exit""",
                            //above command created file name log=C:UsersAdministratorDesktoptest.log but not the image name passed.
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            CreateNoWindow = true
                        };
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: *'code doesnt works as expected'* - could you elaborate on what happens, and what you want to happen?

Comment: its not copying the file as expected with the same name ex: 200.jpeg, as passed parameter(filename).  instead named file as 'log=C:UsersAdministratorDesktoptest.log'.

Comment: That is not true, you have specified the `log` parameter which points to `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.log`. Therefore, the `test.log` file is not the file you want to copy.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, pls let me clarify more. If I am passing static filename as below 20.jpeg, code as below ..  @"/command ""option batch on"" ""option confirm off"" ""open userx:pwdx@10.1.1.1"" ""put C:\Mobile\Attachments\20.jpeg /tmp/"" ""/log=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.log"" ""exit""", the file is copied successfully. The same I want to pass filename dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

resolved issue by using winscp library and code from below url.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#downloading_and_installing_the_assembly